# In Dropzone.JS, how to grab list of all files in queue when performing multiple drops?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I am using the "drop" event and grabbing a list of files from event.dataTransfer.files.

```
var dz = new Dropzone("#dropzone", {
            url: "/api/UploadHandler/",
            maxFileSize: 3000,
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            autoDiscover: false,
            parallelUploads: 3,
        }).on("drop", function (event) {
            console.log(event.dataTransfer.files);
        });
```

If I drop multiple files at once, it returns a list of them all.  If I drop them one at a time, it only returns the file I just dropped and not the other ones in the queue.

Is there any way to get a list of every file in the queue, regardless of when I drop them in the dropzone?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can just call its getQueuedFiles() function.

```
myDropzone.getQueuedFiles();
```

it must return a list of queue files.